# s(n) = kn or s(n) = n/k?

Tags: nt.number-theory

**This is not an important question, just for fun.**

**Definition:**

$\sigma (n)$ =  sum of the positive divisors of $n$.
$s(n)$ =  sum of the proper positive divisors of $n$.

**For  $s(n) = kn$ , where $k$ is a natural number:**

When $k = 1,$ then $n$ is a perfect number which has been discussed a lot.

How about $k = 2,3,4,5,\ldots$?

Based on some computations ( $n < 1.5\cdot 10^9$), I **haven't found**

1. Any odd number satisfying $s(n) = kn$.
2. $s(n) \geq 5n$
3. $s(n) = 4n$

**for $s(n) = n/k$ with natural $ k >1$:**

$n$ must be prime (and thus $k=n$.)

**Conjecture:**

1. If $s(n) = kn$, then $n$ must be even.
2. $s(n) < 5n$
3. $s(n) = n/k$ for a natural $ k >1$ $\iff  n$ is prime .

**Question:**
**Could you provide a counterexample or prove it?**

Comment: Are you asking about the multiply perfect numbers (L.E.Dickson, History of the Theory of Numbers, Vol I, Chapter 1)?

Comment: BTW, I call them baroque numbers.

Answer (score 4):

This is related to some open questions in number theory. See http://oeis.org/A134639 and references/links there.

Conjecture 2 is incorrect, the smallest counterexample is given by $$n=154345556085770649600.$$

Conjecture 3 holds trivially if one notice that for a composite $n$, $s(n)$ is larger than the largest proper divisor of $n$, and thus $s(n)=n/k$ implies $k=1$.